# AngularJS | No errors, yet my Dependency Injection is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I haven't been able to find any answers to my question.

To summarize, I'm trying to accomplish dependency injection via making my directive in the **'directives.js'** file accessible in my controller in the **'controllers.js'** file.

Even in my **'controllers.js'** file when I add the just the square brackets in the module and nothing else,

```js
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular
  .module('blogApp', ['file-directives'])
  // Career Controller
  .controller('CareerCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
   $scope.getCareers = function () {
    $http.get('/career').then(function (response) {
     $scope.careers = response.data;
    });
   };
  
   $scope.getCareer = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/career/' + id).then(function (response) {
     $scope.career = response.data;
    });
   };
  
   $scope.addCareer = function () {
    $http.post('/career', $scope.career).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/career';
    });
   };

   $scope.updateCareer = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.put('/career/' + id, $scope.career).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/career';
    });
   };

   $scope.removeCareer = function (id) {
    $http.delete('/career/' + id).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/career';
    });
   };
  })
  
  // Lifestyle Controller
  .controller('LifestyleCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
   $scope.getLifestyles = function () {
    $http.get('/lifestyle').then(function (response) {
     $scope.lifestyles = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.getLifestyle = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/lifestyle/' + id).then(function (response) {
     $scope.lifestyle = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.addLifestyle = function () {
    $http.post('/lifestyle', $scope.lifestyle).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/lifestyle';
    });
   };

   $scope.updateLifestyle = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.put('/lifestyle/' + id, $scope.lifestyle).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/lifestyle';
    });
   };

   $scope.removeLifestyle = function (id) {
    $http.delete('/lifestyle/' + id).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/lifestyle';
    });
   };
  })
 
  // Travel Controller
  .controller('TravelCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
   $scope.getTravels = function () {
    $http.get('/travel').then(function (response) {
     $scope.travels = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.getTravel = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/travel/' + id).then(function (response) {
     $scope.travel = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.addTravel = function () {
    $http.post('/travel', $scope.travel).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/travel';
    });
   };

   $scope.updateTravel = function () {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.put('/travel/' + id, $scope.travel).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/travel';
    });
   };

   $scope.removeTravel = function (id) {
    $http.delete('/travel/' + id).then(function (response) {
     window.location.href = '#!/travel';
    });
   };
  })
 
  // Main Page Controller
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
   $scope.getCareers = function () {
    $http.get('/career').then(function (response) {
     $scope.careers = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.getLifestyles = function () {
    $http.get('/lifestyle').then(function (response) {
     $scope.lifestyles = response.data;
    });
   };

   $scope.getTravels = function () {
    $http.get('/travel').then(function (response) {
     $scope.travels = response.data;
    });
   };
  });
}());



(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('file-directives', [])
    .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var parsedFile = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var parsedFileSetter = parsedFile.assign;
          
          element.bind('change', function () {
            scope.apply(function () {
              parsedFileSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
          });
        }
      };
    }]);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="blogApp">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Shelby Cherie</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body>

  <header>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/">Shelby Cherie</a>
     </div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="main">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <aside>
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked side-menu">
        <li><a href="#!/career">career</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/lifestyle">lifestyle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/travel">travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/about">about me</a></li>
       </ul>
      </aside>
     </div>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="social-media text-center">
     <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
      <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-footer">
     <p>Website Developed by <a href="#">Derek Hawkins Design</a></p>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </footer>


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-parse-ext.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="routes/routes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="directives/directives.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

my web page will be completely blank with no errors.

**controllers.js**

```
   angular
    .module('blogApp', ['file-directives'])
    // Career Controller
    .controller('CareerCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.getCareers = function () {
            $http.get('/career').then(function (response) {
                $scope.careers = response.data;
            });
        };
```

**directives.js**

```
    angular
     .module('file-directives')
     .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var parsedFile = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
         var parsedFileSetter = parsedFile.assign;

         element.bind('change', function () {
          scope.apply(function () {
            parsedFileSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
     }
    };
   }]);
}());
```

Comment: can you please make it run on jsfiddle ? put your module and controller and directive in jsfiddle, it's much better.

Comment: can you post your html code as well ? may be in jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: I just added in the full controllers.js and directives.js files, along with the index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you failed to load `ngRoute` module in controller.js

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('blogApp', ['ngRoute','file-directives'])
// Career Controller
.controller('CareerCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.getCareers = function () {
        $http.get('/career').then(function (response) {
            $scope.careers = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module('file-directives',[])
     .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var parsedFile = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
         var parsedFileSetter = parsedFile.assign;

          element.bind('change', function () {
                  scope.apply(function () {
                        parsedFileSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                  });
          });
        }
      };
  }]);
```

Comment: I loaded the ngRoute dependency in another routes.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing square brackets when declaring "file-directives"

```
 angular
     .module('file-directives',[])
```

Comment: Whenever I add the dependency brackets, my screen goes blank. When I don't add the dependency brackets, my website works.

Comment: Try to check if you have runtime errors in chrome console

Comment: no runtime errors either. Pardon my ignorance, but what would be the significance in a runtime error?